# Text Substitutions using Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

How do I use Regular Expressions in Notepad++ to add the missing '0' to datetime in my list?

Current List:

```
05/14/12,12:2PM ,me862 
05/21/12,12:17 PM,me862 
05/21/12,12:18 PM,me862 
05/29/12,8:5AM,me862 
05/30/12,9:03 AM,me862 
06/11/12,1:2PM,me862
```

Desired Outcome:

```
05/14/12,12:20 PM,me862 
05/21/12,12:17 PM,me862 
05/21/12,12:18 PM,me862 
05/29/12,8:50 AM,me862 
05/30/12,9:03 AM,me862 
06/11/12,1:20 PM,me862
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex for find:

```
(:\d)([AP]M)
```

And use this for replace:

```
\10 \2
```

---

`(:\d)` matches a `:` and a number, and stores it in `\1` (for the replace).

`([AP]M)` matches either AM or PM and stores it in `\2` (for the replace).

Answer (score 0):

You coul do:

Find what: `(?<!\d)(\d)(?=\s*[pa]m)`
Replace with: `${1}0`  (*Note the space at the end.*)

Make sure that `Regular expression` is checked but not `Match case`